# Erro de conflicting types for ‘login’

Tags: c

Estou fazendo uma tela de login, mas meu código está dando erro:

> conflicting types for ‘login’.

Sou iniciante da área e não estou conseguindo entender o que fazer para arrumar isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```c
typedef struct{
    char login[30];
    char senha[30];
} usuario; usuario u[0];

void tela_login()
{

    FILE *login;
    login = fopen("login.txt", "a"); //"a" para adicionar no txt
    if (login == NULL) {
        printf("\nO arquivo não foi aberto!");
        exit(0);
    }
    system("cls");
    
    char login[30];
    char senha[30];
    int contador;
    
    for(contador = 1;contador<=3;contador++){
    system("cls");
    
    strcpy(u[0].login, "admin");
    strcpy(u[0].senha, "202020");

        printf("Digite o login do usuario ADMIN:  ");
        fgets (u[0].login,30, stdin);
    
        printf("Digite a senha do usuario ADMIN:  ");
        fgets (u[0].senha,30, stdin);

    while(fgets(u[0].login && u[0].senha,30, stdin) != NULL) {
    if((strcmp(login,u[0].login)==0) && (strcmp(senha,u[0].senha)==0)){
        printf("Seja bem vindo");
    }else{
        printf("Login e/ou senha invalidos, tente novamente!");
    }
    }
        printf("Login e/ou senha bloqueado temporariamente");
    }
    fclose(login);

}
```

Comment: Afinal `login` é um FILE ou um array de char? `FILE *login;` e `char login[30];`

Comment: o FILE *login é para a criação do arquivo e depois manipulação e o char login[30] é para informar o tamanho do vetor utilizado para o login, mas vc acha que os dois não podem ter o mesmo nome pois eles estão entrando em conflito? Eu tentei modificar uma vez mas tive problema para compilar o restante do código, então estou recebendo sugestão porque quanto mais eu mexo pior fica e por ser iniciante não sei exatamente o que fazer

Comment: Você não pode dar o mesmo nome para coisas diferentes. Isto é básico em programação.

Comment: Obrigada pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: @anonimo Crie uma resposta com o que comentou para se finalizar esta pergunta com uma resposta válida.